# How to subset multiple times from larger data frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop, subset, data-wrangling

I have the following wide data in a .csv:

| Subj | Show1_judgment1 | Show1_judgment2 | Show1_judgment3 | Show1_judgment4 | Show2_judgment1 | Show2_judgment2 | Show2_judgment3 | Show2_judgment4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 3 | 7 | 2 | 6 |

The columns keep going for the same four judgments for a series of 130 different shows.

I want to change this data into long form so that it looks like this:

| Subj | show | judgment1 | judgment2 | judgment3 | judgment4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | show1 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | show2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | show3 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 5 |

Usually, I would use base r to subset the columns into their own dataframes and then used `rbind` to put them into one dataframe.

But since there are so many different shows, it will be very inefficient to do it like that. I am relatively novice at R, so I can only do very basic for loops, but I think a for loop that subsets the subject column (first column in data) and then groups of 4 sequential columns would do this much more efficiently.

Can anyone help me create a for loop for this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

No `for` loop required,  this is transforming or "pivoting" from wide to long format.

### tidyr

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, -Subj, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("show", ".value"))
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#    Subj show  judgment1 judgment2 judgment3 judgment4
#   <int> <chr>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1     1 Show1         3         2         5         6
# 2     1 Show2         3         2         5         7
# 3     2 Show1         1         3         5         4
# 4     2 Show2         3         4         1         6
# 5     3 Show1         1         2         6         2
# 6     3 Show2         3         7         2         6
```

### data.table

Requires `data.table-1.14.3`, relatively new (or from github).

```r
data.table::melt(
  dat, id.vars = "Subj",
  measure.vars = measure(show, value.name, sep = "_"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Will use this method from now on.